# What are the purposes of pvc pipe with open end in my crawl space?

Tags: pipe, crawlspace

[image: One end goes to outside but no exit seen; the other end open]
[image: One end goes into the ground; the other end goes up and cut open]
I have two PVC pipes in my crawl space with open end, one pipe with open end goes into ground of the crawl space, one goes out to outside of the house but no exit can be seen outside.
Are they abandoned pipes? Can I cut them?

Comment: No way to tell without tracing them back.

Comment: I don't know how to share the pictures,  but the other end of these two pipe are not connected to anything. They are cut open

Comment: Sorry if i did not make it clear. There are two pipes, one pipe goes into the ground on one end and has open cut on the other end; one pipe goes towards outside of the house (but no exit can be seen) and has open cut on the other end.

Comment: @Jenna you need to [edit] your question and use the "sun & mountains" button to add pics - you can't add them down here in the comments.

Comment: Thank you brhans, I added two pictures but not sure if I did it right

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should leave them alone until you can deternine where the other end goes and whats it for.

For instance the one going outside, may be going up within the wall.

The one going into the ground may be a disused pipe.  But you still need to know where it goes. Then you can decide if you are able to cap it after cutting it